# owl carousel items are not working when appended dynamically using ajax,jquery

Tags: jquery, html, owl-carousel

owl carousel items are not working when appended dynamically using ajax,jquery
below is my ajax code..any help will be really appreciated..

Thanks in advance

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "urllinks",
                data: 'id='+id,
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                var locationoffers='';
                locationoffers+='<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">';
                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                    locationoffers+='<div class="item"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/uploads/location_offers/'+data[i].image+'"  alt="Location Logo" /></a><span class="tocenter"> <h3>'+data[i].tittle+'</h3></span></div><div class="desc"><span> <p>'+data[i].message+'</p> </span></div><br><div class="tocenter"><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="btn green">Grabit</a></div> </div>';
                });

            locationoffers+='</div>';

               $('#display_adds').html(locationoffers);
              $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();


        }


   });

     }
```

[This is the error output iam getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOwwy.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

when you display owl carousel after ajax call you need to initialize it after receiving the response so try putting the carousel inside the function

```
  function init_carousel() {
     $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();
  };
```

and call the function when the ajax response is successfull to refresh the carousel. And also for it to initialize on page load jus call the function in:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   init_carousel();
});
```

Comment: Hi..thank you for your reply..i have already tried in this way..when i am trying to append,only one item(image)..is adding in carousel and remaining are missing out alignment..i have attached..screenshot off that also..you check for reference,,,

Comment: i am also facing the same issue. all the images are stacked one after the other. maybe the slider is not able to initialize properly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer, try using owlCarousel properties to control the behaviour as:

```
$('.searchPageGallery').owlCarousel({
        margin:0,
        nav:true,
        loop:true,
        stagePadding:0,
        center:true,
        dots:false,
        lazyLoad:true,
        items:1,
        responsiveClass:true,
        responsive:{
            0:{
                items:1,
                nav:true,
                dots:false
            },
            1025:{
                items:1,
                nav:true,
                dots:false
            },
            1200:{
                items:1,
                nav:true,
                nav:true
            }
        }
    });
```